# Bluetooth pairing with BLE not working in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was trying to pair my android   with a `BLE` device. The Problem is when I call for the pairing request  activity, The dialog box appeared. But when I entered my password , it is not being paired or `onActivityResult` is not being called. So what to do for pairing successfully ?

```
   private void startBluetoothPairing(BluetoothDevice device) {
    String ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST = "android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST";
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    String EXTRA_DEVICE = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    String EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT";
    int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 0;
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ((Activity) appContext).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
   }
```

OnActivityResult is not being called.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.v("TAG","Bluetooth Device!!");
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = data.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            data.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY).writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
            byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
            parcel.recycle();
            bluetoothDevice.setPin(bytes);
            bluetoothDevice.createBond();
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem solved :**
**Updated code :**

Registered broadCasterReciever during application launching

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    appContext.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver,intentFilter);
```

Implementation of broadcastReciever.

```
    private  String BLE_PIN= "000012";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action))
                {
                    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    bluetoothDevice.setPin(BLE_PIN.getBytes());
                    Log.e("TAG","Auto-entering pin: " + BLE_PIN);

                }
           }
      };
```

And I called **device.createBond()** after discovering the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i was using and it worked well for me.

Pair with the device

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
                    BluetoothActivity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
                    device.createBond();
```

BroadcastReceiver to check if device paired

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String name = device.getName();
                String address = device.getAddress();
                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    //Device Paired
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Unregister receiver in onDestroy

```
BluetoothActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Comment: Is it pairing with passkey ?

Comment: @mahbubcseju Yes

Comment: But using your method, No dialog box is appeared  for password. I need pairing with passkey . No automated way is needed.

Comment: @mahbubcseju I just checked and it works for me. Dialog box is shown for devices that take standard passkey(0000 or 1234). Sometimes instead of a dialog box, a notification is shown(for pairing between devices).It didn't ask for any passkey when i tried to pair with my bluetooth headphone but it got paired. Maybe your BLE device is a newer one that can pair without a passkey?